# Analyze Performance in c# (without using code) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

How can I measure performance of my code in Visual Studio  without using code such as StopWatch...

I have two methods for performing a specific task one that includes many "else if" statements and i would like to compare them. How can I do so ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't u want to use a StopWatch?

Comment: Buy or find a free performance profiler.

Comment: @VP Because adding code to my existing code will alter the performance even if it will alter it slightly.

Comment: @VP. Yes, that is inherent to the nature of *any* form of performance analysis, and it is *impossible* to avoid no matter what you do.  This is why benchmarking microoptimizations is so hard, the benchmarking code itself, along with the noise of the system, overwhelms the actual difference in performance of the real code.  Usually this is a sign that you're trying to optimize something that you shouldn't, unless you *really* know what you're doing.  If your performance change is small that you're struggling to measure it, it's likely small enough to ignore either way.

Comment: @User2505650 I believe Servy's comment was directed at your last comment, and it *is* important so make sure you read it.

Comment: @user2505650 You said (somewhere in a comment) that you want to actually measure performance of a Console app. You do realize that has nothing to do with Windows Phone, right? So, what are you trying to achieve by that? Also, "else if" statements are very very quick... unless you want to execute millions of them in a second. I'm afraid that your general approach might be wrong (no offence). Maybe you can share the code of the methods with us, or give us some additional info?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the free trial of a performance analyzer such as [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). It does some pretty in depth analysis.

Comment: Thank you but I am not looking for such thing as a trial version !

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a profiler (although for small bits of code sometimes using a stopwatch for wall clock timing is not a bad thing).

MS has some good documentation on Windows phone profiling (I assume this is what you want as your question is tagged Windows phone 8) here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202934%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Also look at profiling tools, most have a free trial.  My personal favorite is JetBrains dotTrace (not sure if this does windows phone though)

Comment: Thank you yes i am developping a WP8 application but before i would like to make some tests on a console application, do you have any documentation or advices for it?

Comment: For a simple console app I would probably use a stopwatch, running the code a few thousand times to improve accuracy.

Otherwise, use a profiler such as [dotTrace performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).  It's easy to use, has a free trial and has good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 (Professional or higher) has an excellent built in profiler. If you don't have 2013, check out [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/), as it has an excellent one as well.

Comment: I have the 2013 version how can I use it?

Comment: I'm guessing you won't see it in Express...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: i have the Professional Version , except from WP how can I measure performance in a console application?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS2013 and windows phone 8.1 than use default performance and diagnostic tool in VS.

[image]

You can also use windows phone power tools shipped with VS2013 in **TOOLS--->WINDOWS PHONE 8.1--->Developer Power tool** to check the performance and the app on emulator and also on real device. it is very powerful tool for diagnostics and performance, See following link for details

[Test and troubleshoot apps with the Windows Phone Developer Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629255.aspx)